# Example from tutorial does not work: problem with edge style in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I tried an example from the TikZ tutorial:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfsys} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{topaths}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzset {
terminal/.style={
rounded rectangle,% : the shape
minimum size=6mm,% size 
very thick,draw=black!50,% border 
top color=white,bottom color=black!20,% filling with shading 
font=\ttfamily % font 
},
nonterminal/.style={
rectangle,% : the shape
minimum size=6mm,% size 
very thick,draw=red!50!black!50,% border 
top color=white,bottom color=red!50!black!20,% filling with shading 
font=\itshape % font 
},
point/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt,fill=red},
skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}}
} % \tikzset

\begin{document}

text

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep=1mm,column sep=2mm] {
% First row:
& & & & & & & & & & & \node (plus) [terminal] {+};\\
% Second row:
\node (p1) [point] {}; &
\node (ui1) [nonterminal] {unsigned integer}; &
\node (p2) [point] {}; &
\node (dot) [terminal] {.}; &
\node (p3) [point] {}; &
\node (digit) [terminal] {digit}; &
\node (p4) [point] {}; &
\node (p5) [point] {}; &
\node (p6) [point] {}; &
\node (e) [terminal] {E}; &
\node (p7) [point] {}; &
 &
\node (p8) [point] {}; &
\node (ui2) [nonterminal] {unsigned integer}; &
\node (p9) [point] {}; &
\node (p10) [point] {};\\
% Third row:
& & & & & & & & & & & \node (minus)[terminal] {-};\\
};
\graph[use existing nodes]  {
p1 -> ui1 -- p2 -> dot -- p3 -> digit -- p4
-- p5 -- p6 -> e -- p7 -- p8 -> ui2 -- p9 -> p10;
%p4 ->[skip loop=-5mm] 
%p3;
% p2 ->%[skip loop=5mm] 
% p5;
% p6 ->%[skip loop=-11mm]
%  p9;
% p7 ->%[vh path] 
% plus -> %[hv path] 
% p8;
% p7 ->%[vh path] 
% minus -> %[hv path] 
% p8;
};
\path (p4) edge [->,skip loop=-5mm] (p3)
(p2) edge [->,skip loop=5mm] (p6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That code works. However, if I replace the edges with `skip loop` by the ones in the path, so that it looks like in the example, LaTeX tells me:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
...
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/skip loop' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.90 }
      ;
```

I Actually uncommented

```
% p2 ->%[skip loop=5mm] 
% p5;
```

The same thing happens with the parts of the graph 
containing `vh path` and `hv path`. What am I doing wrong?

It seems as if styles of nodes work but styles of edges do not. 
I dont understand this....

Maybe the log file for the ok-case i added below gives some hint. 
I feel, it does not look very smooth, does it?!

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (format=pdflatex 2014.8.9)  9 AUG 2014 20:02
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input test.tex
(./test.tex (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks19
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks21
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks22
\pgffor@toks=\toks23
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopat
hs.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryposit
ioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibra
rygraphs.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex 2010/10/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.misc.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.t
ex
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/10/07 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.3)
)) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 33.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no @ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!

Overfull \hbox (30.17874pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 93--94
[][] 
 []

[1

{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10189 strings out of 493315
 199059 string characters out of 6145894
 256968 words of memory out of 5000000
 13455 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4154 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,14n,79p,429b,905s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/shar
e/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 33969 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 18 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 25 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Which code exactly is producing the error? The code you just posted doesn't produce errors in my system even if I uncomment the commented-out parts.

Comment: improved my post accordingly. ...
So if code is ok on your system, the problem is not in code but in my system, probably, right?

Comment: Yes. As I see from your `.log` file, your system uses PGF version 2.10; the newest version is 3.0 (that's the one in my system), so I suspect it's all about outdated packages. You could try updating PGF or, even better, your LaTeX system.

Comment: Hello Gonzalo, that hint helped. well my suse distribution offers that tex and that tikz.
Was a little cumbersome to update all, including auctex and octave(!) but now: all right and all problems gone. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem due to using version 2.10 while the code requires version 3 of TikZ/PGF

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)